# How to divide by a float in PHP?

Tags: php

I need to determine if a given number `x` is divisble by `y` in [PHP](http://php.net/), being `y` a float, specifically 0.05.

But when I do it,

```
if ($number % 0.05 === 0) {
    // Continue
}
```

I recieve the following PHP warning:

> Division by zero

What can I do to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: http://bit.ly/ZF9nDH maybe this will help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definision of modulus is as follows:

> In computing, the modulo (sometimes called modulus) operation finds the remainder of division of one number by another.

Another way of expressing `a % b` is: `a - b * floor(a/b)`

Therefore, you could define your own function:

```
function mod($a,$b) {return $a-$b*floor($a/$b);}
```

And simply call it. For example, calling `mod(0.08,0.05)` will return `0.03`.

Comment: I was too late to post the same answer, +1 thought :)

Answer (score 0):

You could multiply both numbers by 100.

```
if (($number * 100) % 5 === 0) {
    // Continue
}
```

Comment: Not very flexible. What if y = 0.0000005 ?